# Realm for Java App

Tags: java, android, spring, realm

I would like to know if it is possible to use a Realm Database (ROS) with a Spring App.

I explain my problem :

I have a Android APP, that connect to ROS, by login and Password, for saving Android information.

But i also have a Spring App that will provide other data as picture or other data.

I would like to protect my Spring APP access by a token access. The problem is that my token is based on login and password, but this information is stored on realm base.

How can i ask with my SpringApp to retrieve this information, and perform the token generation and verification ?

Sincerely,

K.G

Comment: Realm-Java only works on Android, to access a Sync Realm server-side you can use the NodeJS SDK, and possibly also the .NET SDK (not sure about this one), and it requires a feature token which is not free